# WPF ListView horizontal scrollbar is not displayed unless vertical scrolling is done

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView containing some ListViewItems. So, Vertical scrollbar is needed. The ListViewItems contains strings and each string is of different length(Width of ListViewItems is Auto). The last string is lengthy and contains about above 100 characters. So, horizontal scrollbar is needed.
Initially while launching, the vertical scroll bar is displayed. But horizontal scrollbar is not displayed.
But after the vertical scrolling to the last item which contains the long string, the horizontal scroll bar gets displayed and it stays even when I vertically upwards.
How can the horizontal scrollbar shown initially itself when the ListViewItems contains strings that is large and exceeds the current display?

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" Margin="0,0,0,40">
        <ListViewItem Content="O" />
        <ListViewItem Content="1" />
        <ListViewItem Content="2" />
        <ListViewItem Content="3" />
        <ListViewItem Content="4" />
        <ListViewItem Content="5" />
        <ListViewItem Content="6" />
        <ListViewItem Content="7O" />
        <ListViewItem Content="8O" />
        <ListViewItem Content="9O" />
        <ListViewItem Content="1O" />
        <ListViewItem Content="1O1" />
        <ListViewItem Content="1O2" />
        <ListViewItem Content="Ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo1QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQA" />
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please do post a [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please find the updated question with sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default the virtualization by `ListView` is on. So if you switch off the virtualization, you will reach that all entries will be created initially and so the horizontal scrollbar will be activated.

```
<ListView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. Also, when I am using ListView with margin, a gap is appearing between the last listviewitem and horizontal scrollbar. Without the horizontal scrollbar, there is no gap. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you. ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"  solved the problem.